# Regexp: repeated concrete digit var vs repeated any digit var (Java)

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

myString.match("[\d]*") gives true for 12345 and 77777

but what I am looking would give false for 12345 and true for 7777

Comment: Why 7777 is ok, but 12345 not? What kind of numbers are you looking for?

Comment: understanding the approach, is something abstract so no explanation thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(\d)\1*\D
```

would test for repeated same digits followed by non-digit.  the `\1` refers to the value matched by the `(...)` which would be the first digit.

(not sure what you want at the end - you might want to swap `$` (end of line) for `\D` - but you need something so that 778 fails)

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by Andrew Cooke is a great start - his expression for catching the repeated numbers work perfectly. Nevertheless, in order to find that there are only the repeated numbers, I believe that you need to use boundary matchers, as explained in  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html.

I created a little fragment of code that show you how to perform it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d)\\1*$");
  String[] testArray = {"1111", "2111", "1111 ", "1111 2", "1234", "9999"};
  for (int i=0; i&lt;teste.length; i++) {
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testArray[i]);
     boolean found=false;
     while (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println("Text " + matcher.group() + " found at " + matcher.start()+" ending at index "+matcher.end());
         found=true;
     }
     if (!found) {
        System.out.println("not found for "+testArray[i]);
     }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.